# Extending 3rd party class as Hadoop Writable with proxy

Tags: java, serialization, hadoop, proxy-classes, writable

I have a third-party class that I am trying to use in Hadoop, and thus need to make have it implement `Writable`. The problem is that the way Hadoop uses `Writable` is to create an object `o = SomeObject()`, then call `o.readFields(in)` to de-serialize, and in my situation I cannot create the empty object:

```
public abstract class Cube {
    protected final int size;
    protected Cube(int size) { this.size = size; }
}
```

Note `size` is `final`.

```
public class RealCube {
    public Cube(int size) { super(size); }
}
```

Here `RealCube` only has one super constructor to call, and that construtor sets the `final` variable in the abstract super class.

```
public class RealCubeWritable implements Writable {
    public void readFields(DataInput in) {
        /* yikes! need to set the size */
    }
}
```

When we get down to trying to implement `RealCubeWritable`, I cannot have a `RealCubeWritable()` constructor, and I cannot know the actual `size` until the `DataInput` stream is examined.

So it seems like the only way to do this in Hadoop is to use a wrapper. What I am wondering is if there is a way to use a wrapper, but have `RealCubeWritable` still behave like `RealCube`? I've looked into using Dynamic Proxy classes, but I'm not sure if this will work (or how to actually do it).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you genuinely have no control over the Cube object then i'm not sure you have many (pleasant) options:

- I'm not sure i understand what you mean by a wrapper or proxy object - either way final is final so you'd need to create a copy of the class without the final flags
- You might be able to use a nasty reflection hack to allow you to un-final the size field, and then set the field value also through reflection, but that may cause some undefined behaviour if Cube initialised other variables from size in the constructor
- You could write your own [Serialization](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/Serialization.html) class, which will allow you to create a new instance of RealCube (not the most efficient, but it will work) for each object (rather than utilizing traditional hadoop object reuse)
- Is the domain of `size` relatively small? (i.e. it can only be a limited set / range of values). If so you could create an instance of RealCube for each valid size value, and again, using a custom Serialization implementation, pick the right Cube instance based upon the size read from the input stream

Comment: Having control over Cube is possible, it's just undesirable because it means upstream changes that I have to maintain. I think the win though is worth it -- there are a lot of undesirable properties (in addition to the problem that I mentioned), that would result in lots of unnecessary copying and allocation.

I think the reflection idea is what I originally had in mind. I don't really know anything about the details, but this seemed relevant: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html

Comment: You can only use Proxy with interfaces though, and i'm still not sure how this would resolve your `final` problem